# .dll files and FileCopy function didnt help me to copy trade

Tags: dll, copy-paste, mql4, metatrader4

i need **Expert Advisor** to  copy trade from an **mt4** account to another **mt4** account on same pc and i want run it on **vps** server,

i write File but i cant send it to common files of another mt4 because of security issues of **mql**. i cant use **.dll** files because **vps** dont allow me use them. i dont have any site *to send **webrequest** function*.what solvation do u offer me?